# SQL Query No Error Messages

Tags: php, sql

EDIT: Found the error. The sting replace statement was adding an extra space. Fixed now, thanks.

I've been looking at this too long, I can't find the error.

Here's what I've got:

```
echo $client_name." - ".$location;  
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spc_clients WHERE (client_name='".$client_name."' AND location='".$location."')") or die(mysql_error());  
while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  
    // Other code...
}
```

When I echo, I get 'Client1' and 'Location1". When I put the SQL query into PHPMyAdmin, and replace those values, the query runs fine and brings up results. On the page it's on, I get nothing.

I have no syntax errors, and the mysql_error isn't coming back with anything either.

What am I missing?

Comment: One thing you're missing is protection from [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: shouldn't it be `AND` instead of `&&`. Also you should echo your actual `$query` and run that through PHPMyAdmin instead of doing manual replacements

Comment: Also you are not specifying a db connector as a second argument to your mysql_query, which could be causing issues depending on the code higher up.

Comment: @jack: you definitely can't say from the above snippet. The poster can apply various sanitization/filtration before this code.

Comment: @Julien is right about the &&. It really should be AND. Additionally, make sure you are running mysql_escape_real_string on the strings themselves to assure you are escaping stuff so that the query doesn't get thrown off. Julien is also correct in suggesting that you echo the exact query from your php code so that you can beter visualize the issue.

Comment: @julien: mysql_query will take the last opened connection. Unless the poster closed the connection prior, it'l take last alive connection by default.

Comment: @EmmanuelG `&&` is valid incase of MYSQL too.

Comment: I changed the statement to AND instead of && and am still having the same error. I should have noticed that, but PHPMyAdmin took && fine. *shrugs* Still have the error. 
The database is connected, I have other queries on the page running, I've only included the lines of code that are actually not working on my page.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM spc_clients WHERE client_name="'.$client_name.'" AND location="'.$location.'" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM spc_clients WHERE client_name='%s' AND location='%s'",trim($client_name),trim($location));
$query = mysql_query($query);
```